# How to print a string, which includes special characters and was read from a file? How to print it without special characters?

Tags: c, string

I have following function:

```
int Printf(const char *s, int length)
{
   int i=0;
   while(i < length)      
   {
      printf("%c", s[i]);
      i++;
   }
}
```

But if I call it with a non null-terminated string like "Hello World\n" which I read from a file, it prints *Hello World\n* without making a new line, so it prints *\n* explicitly. What is wrong with my function?

Comment: Do you mean it really prints "Hello World\n", i.e. a backslash and n? This can't happen, because \n is replaced with char(13) at compile time.

Comment: @satuon: No, it happens, because I read such string from a file

Comment: Aren't Pascal-type strings those with the length specified in `[0]`?

Comment: @Linus Kleen: ok, let's say it is a special-string, not a Pascal-type

Comment: What are you using to read the file?  Some functions, such as `fgets`, will terminate strings for you.

Comment: @psihodelia Do you mean you wrote "Hello World\n" in a file? Then that's your problem, special characters are converted by the compiler, not the printf function. If you have `char a[2] = "a\n";`, it's equivalent to `char a[2] = { 'a', 13 };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewritten my function so:

```
int Printf(char *s, int length)
{
   int   i=0;
   char  c = '\0',
         special='\\',
         newline ='n', 
         creturn ='r', 
         tab     ='t';
   while(i < length)
   {
      if(c == special) 
      { 
         if( s[i] == newline )
            printf("\n"); 
         else if(s[i] == creturn)
            printf("\r"); 
         else if(s[i] == tab)
            printf("\t"); 
         else if(s[i] == special)
            printf("\\"); 
      } 
      else if (s[i] != '\\')
         printf("%c", s[i]); 
      c = s[i];
      i++;
   }
}
```

and now it does work right!

Comment: ok ... but 'wrong' combinations do not print at all with your code: "foo\bar" prints "fooar" (that's ok! I'm just bringing it up!). You could code to ignore the '\' (print "foobar") or print everything ("foo\bar").

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong, but I guess the `\n` is essentially in the string. When you write `\n` inside a string in your C/C++ program the compiler will replace it with the proper linebreak. However this doesn't happen if the `\n` is in your text (essentially being `"\\n"`).

Where is the string set? Seems like you might have to handle the escaped characters yourself.

Btw. depending on your compiler you should be able to use something like this, which is a lot simplier:

```
printf("%*s", length, s);
```

Edit:
Just read your comment above. You'll have to handle the `\n` -> linebreak replacement yourself if you read the string from a file. `printf()` won't handle it for you.

Comment: Please read my updated original question. I have not a C-type string, it is not a null-terminated one.

Comment: I know, the * in the format string says the compiler to read the length from the next parameter. The string doesn't have to be null terminated for this to work.

Comment: @Mario: I have printf function which doesn't support it (because it's for a special embedded system)

Comment: Then use your own code as written above, just make sure to replace escape sequences yourself.

Comment: @Mario: ok, thanks. It looks like your solution is the best option.

Comment: @Mario: well... it doesn't work even on a host which support complete ANSI printf :(

Answer (score 1):

Special characters are handled by the compiler, not by printf. They are converted during compile time, so

```
char a[] = "a\n";
```

becomes equivalent to

```
char a[] = { 'a', 13, 0 };
```

printf never sees "\n", the compiler has converted that to 13 beforehand.
And printf doesn't have the ability to convert special characters. When you read "Hello World\n" from a file, you can't expect it to be converted by the compiler.